# What scripts/calls do you usually include in your Git pre-commit hooks?

Tags: git, githooks, pre-commit-hook

I want to know what are the best practices in setting up your pre-commit hooks. What the other developers using Git include in their pre-commit scripts.

In my case, assuming I'm working on a PHP project and having OCD tendencies sometimes - my pre-commit hook includes:

- PHP syntax checker - commit will fail if there are syntax errors in the committed PHP files.
- pngout - if the committed file is a png image. pngout will automatically optimize/compress  that file.
- JavaScript syntax checker (in my to-do list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual policy to check for git `pre-commit` hook is about:

- **comment message** (formatting, reference to a work item of sorts)
- **number of files** (too many means the commit isn't a coherent "unit", but one large set of files)
- **presence of specific files** (like in [this hook](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-git-commit-hooks-to-prevent-stupid-mistakes))